# admin-ajax.php error 500

Tags: ajax, 500-internal-error

I keep looking my error , but I can't find it.
My php and js script works fine 5 month ago when I let them to dedicate myself to design
Normally this ajax query must be launch from my plugin ( and works fine before) , but to try to resolve my problem I relocate them to template without change.

Could you please help me to understand where is located my error ?
I have always Error 500 and I can't have any errors to help me to resolve .

Form :

```
<div id="FormLogin" >
<form id="LogAtv" method="post" action="atv_user_login" >
<p> Id User</p>
    <input id='IdUser' name="user_login" type="text" required="required" autocomplete="username">
<p> Password</p>
    <input id="PasswordUser" type="password" name="user_pass" autocomplete="new-password" required="required">
    
    <input type="submit" name="Atvsubmit" id="btn_Login" value="Valider &#xf058">
    <p class="status"></p>
</form>
```

PhP:

```
`function atv_user_admin() {
wp_enqueue_script('script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/script/test.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
wp_localize_script('script', 'wpAjax', array('ajaxUrl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}
add_action('login_enqueue_scripts', 'atv_user_admin');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'atv_user_admin');
add_action('wp_ajax_atv_user_login','handle_user_login');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_atv_user_login', 'handle_user_login');

function handle_user_login(){
    
    $log_param = isset($_REQUEST['log-param'])?trim($_REQUEST['log-param']):"";
    if($log_param == "login_data" ){
        $info = array();
        $info['user_login'] = $_POST[user_login];
        $info['user_password'] = $_POST[user_pass];
        $info['remember'] = true;
        //$isActivated = get_user_meta($info->ID, 'is_activated', true);
        $user_signon = wp_signon($info, false);
        
        if(is_wp_error($user_signon)){
            $error_string = $user_signon->get_error_message();
            echo json_encode(array('status' => 0));
            echo '<div id="message" class="error"><p>' . $error_string . '</p></div>';
        }else{
            if($isActivated !== 1){
                echo json_encode(array('useremailauth' =>'Description text'));

            }else{
                echo json_encode(array('status' => 1));
                wp_clear_auth_cookie();
                wp_set_auth_cookie( $info->ID, true, is_ssl() );
                wp_user_settings($info->ID);
                setcookie('useratv','connected', time() + (3600), "/"); 
                wp_set_current_user($info->ID, $username);
                
                if(is_user_logged_in()){
                    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
                    $userpicture = "test";
                    echo json_encode(array('userpicture' => $userpicture));
                }
            }
        }
    }
wp_die();
}`
```

jquery:ajax (test.js)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $(function(){
        $('#btn_Login').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var formdata = $('#LogAtv').serialize();
            formdata += '&action=atv_user_login&log-param=login_data';
            console.log(formdata);
            $.ajax({ 
                url:wpAjax.ajaxUrl,
                data:formdata,
                type:'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    if(response.status == 1) {
                        alert('user exist');
                        console.log("UserCorrecte");
                    }
                    if(response.status !== 1) {
                        alert("User does not exist");
                        console.log(response.errorstype);
                    }
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    console.log(request.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: A 500 error is typically a coding error. Is there anything in your PHP error log? If you look at the actual response to the request in the browser's dev tools what do you see?

Comment: I have already follow this advice but I don't know if I well understand :

Comment: I have already follow this advice but I don't know if I well understand : `"POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 47 website.com "https://website.com/wp-admin/`. The log says me that ajax is well called from main domain but the console says it called from subdomain `status of 500 () : https://sub1.domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`.
I have already verify if called several time Ajax , but this is not the case

Comment: that wouldn't cause a HTTP 500 on its own, you need to look at your PHP error log to find out what the actual error is. `HTTP 500` is a super generic something went wrong message

Comment: I currently searching my error, but could you please tell me if each error calling admin-ajax.php define an error before to call this one or not necessary ? 
Now I have error 400 after an oversight and i can't find any error with Jquery or Ajax.

Comment: only a strange thing , I have multiple call of ajax in different location : `/* <![CDATA[ */
var _wpUtilSettings = {"ajax":{"url":"\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php"}};
/* ]]> */` `x_Url : "admin_url(admin-ajax.php)";` and `/* <![CDATA[ */
var wpAjax = {"ajaxUrl":"https:\/\/sub1.website.com\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php"};
var ajaxSender = {"ajax_url":"https:\/\/sub1.website.com\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","nonce":"3c9185bb44"};
/* ]]> */`

Comment: Resolved : dataType: 'json' was unnecessary