# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

Tags: internal-server-error

I'm getting the error below...

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 () /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php:1

However, after checking the server, running the ownership and permission command, and adjusting all security settings, I'm still getting the error. Any suggestions?

Comment: duplicate https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/408540/168823

Answer (score 0):

Permissions is not the reason of 500 status. [As answered here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/admin-ajax-error-500-2/), you should try disabling plugins and themes. Examine error log to see what is true reason.

Comment: I have already troubleshoot all plugins and theme... Error logs showed ownership and permission issues that's why I mentioned that...

Comment: Ok. Can you show exact error log message? Generate the error again, note the date and time, then immediately check your server error log for any errors that occurred during that time period